# Библиотека datedropper

Tags: javascript, html, css

Помогите, пожалуйста. Установил input с календарем от библиотеки datedropper (https://felicegattuso.com/projects/datedropper/). Все работает ок, но почему то вместо галочки отображается буква "а", шрифты закинул в папку с проектом. Помогите, пожалуйста. Заранее спасибо[image]/8UrYb.png

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]